# Would stainless steel corrode in this electrolytic cell I designed?

Tags: redox, electrolysis

1. As far as I know, stainless steel is resistant to corrosion due to an inert oxide layer formed by the other alloy metals. I am learning about redox reactions right now so I am no expert; but since stainless is not to be used as a anode, I am wondering why is it allowed as an cathode? Wouldn't the oxide layer be reduced, forming oxygen gas and thus exposing more of the metal and lead to corrosion?
2. I have also read that stainless forms hexavalent chromium when being used as a anode, so is that because it gains extra oxygen atoms due to the oxidizing process? If so, it should be okay to put it in a high oxygen environment, right?
3. When using a carbon anode, does it only produce carbon dioxide? And is this gas formed from ions, or is there oxygen gas present first, which later reacts with the carbon?

Here is my design, I do not care at the moment that the gases are being mixed:[image]

4. I plan on using sodium acetate as a salt in a future project, it produces carbon dioxide and hydroxide ions as some of the products. Similar to question three, is oxygen gas ever produced in this reaction?

In the future I would hope to have proper equipment and materials to build a cell like this one: [link](http://woelen.homescience.net/science/chem/exps/precision_electrolysis/index_acetate.html)
Also if any of these questions are too broad to answer please let me know, I am quite new to stackexchange. Thanks in advanced!